# Google Cloud Build failed to read env variable from github

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, github-actions

Im currently building a Next.js project and using Github Actions, Dockerfile and Google Cloud to deploy my project(by watching tutorial at youtube; its my first time). So based on my understanding, my github action will push the code directly to Google Cloud Run(GCR), where it will be live on the Internet; and Google Cloud Build(GCB)? idk i just follow tutorial. So the problem is my Github Action can read the env variable, i tried to echo it and it works. However, my GCB failed.

[image: build failed]

Here is my Github Action workflow yml currently:

```
name: simplifiedimaluum

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

env:
  PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.CLOUD_RUN_PROJECT_NAME }}
  REGION: asia-southeast1
  REPO_NAME: simplifiedimaluum
  NEXT_PUBLIC_REDIS_URL: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_REDIS_URL }}

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    name: Setup, Build, and Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Authenticate with Google Cloud
      - id: "auth"
        uses: "google-github-actions/auth@v0"
        with:
          credentials_json: "${{ secrets.CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}"

      # Setup gcloud CLI/SDK
      - name: Set up Cloud SDK
        uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0

      - name: Authorize Docker push
        run: gcloud auth configure-docker

      - name: Prints NEXT_PUBLIC_REDIS_URL
        run: echo $NEXT_PUBLIC_REDIS_URL

      - name: Build and tag the docker image
        run: |-
          docker build \
            --build-arg=NEXT_PUBLIC_REDIS_URL=$NEXT_PUBLIC_REDIS_URL \
            --tag gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$GITHUB_SHA .

      - name: Push the image to the Google Container Registry (GCR)
        run: |-
          docker push gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$GITHUB_SHA

      - name: Deploy
        run: |-
          gcloud run deploy $REPO_NAME \
          --region $REGION \
          --image gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$GITHUB_SHA \
          --platform "managed" \
          --quiet
```

and here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18.17.1-slim

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY . .

RUN npm ci --only=production

ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_REDIS_URL

ENV _NEXT_PUBLIC_REDIS_URL=$NEXT_PUBLIC_REDIS_URL

# Echo the environment variable for verification
RUN echo "NEXT_PUBLIC_REDIS_URL: $_NEXT_PUBLIC_REDIS_URL"

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

as you can see on both file i tried to echo the `NEXT_PUBLIC_REDIS_URL` to try to see if it works.

Comment: What exactly is the error that you're getting? From the attached snapshot, your GHA workflow seems to be successful.

Comment: can you share the error log also the tutorial you are following